# FormBuilder form is not visible on public page

Tags: wordpress, contacts, forms, formbuilder

I am building a form with the help of the FormBuilder extension in CiviCRM.
Currently I am using Version 5.57.0 in Wordpress 6.1.1 and I need to embed the form in a public page and I am adding the shortcode with the name of the form explained in the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/)

> [civicrm component="afform" name="afformFormularioEducaciN"]

but the problem is that **the form is not visible on the public page**:

[image]

**the form if it is visible** when i am connected in an admin session:

[image]

It is important to tell you that the configuration of the form in FormBuilder is (I assume) the correct one:

Permission: **Add Contacts**

[image]

Security: **Open Access**
Allowed Actions: **Create**

[image]

Form page: https://www.redmaternoinfantil.org.mx/educacion/

Comment: webform-civicrm is a drupal module, so removing the tag

Comment: You should try fixing your Javascript errors first - then see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me: I have created a profile to embed a shortcode with the help of the indicated documentation https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/

> [civicrm component="profile" mode="y" gid="x"]